# Issue with SQL query for activity stream/feed

Tags: sql, android-activity, stream, feed

I'm building an application that allows users to recommend music to each other, and am having trouble building a query that would return a 'stream' of recommendations that involve both the user themselves, as well as any of the user's friends. This is my table structure:

Recommendations

```
ID     Sender     Recipient    [other columns...]
--     ------     ---------    ------------------
r1     u1         u3           ...
r2     u3         u2           ...
r3     u4         u3           ...
```

Users

```
ID      Email      First Name   Last Name     [other columns...]
---     -----      ----------   ---------     ------------------
u1      ...        ...          ...           ...
u2      ...        ...          ...           ...
u3      ...        ...          ...           ...
u4      ...        ...          ...           ...
```

Relationships

```
ID      Sender     Recipient     Status       [other columns...]
---     ------     ---------     --------     ------------------
rl1     u1         u2            accepted     ...
rl2     u3         u1            accepted     ...
rl3     u1         u4            accepted     ...
rl4     u3         u2            accepted     ...
```

So for user 'u4' (who is friends with 'u1'), I want to query for a 'stream' of recommendations relevant to u4. This stream would include all recommendations in which either the sender or recipient is u4, as well as all recommendations in which the sender or recipient is u1 (the friend).

This is what I have for the query so far:

```
 SELECT * FROM recommendations
  WHERE recommendations.sender IN 
    ( SELECT sender FROM relationships WHERE recipient='u4' AND status='accepted' 
      UNION 
      SELECT recipient FROM relationships WHERE sender='u4' AND status='accepted') 
 OR recommendations.recipient IN 
    ( SELECT sender FROM relationships WHERE recipient='u4' AND status='accepted' 
      UNION 
      SELECT recipient FROM relationships WHERE sender='u4' AND status='accepted')
 UNION
 SELECT * FROM recommendations
 WHERE recommendations.sender='u4' OR recommendations.recipient='u4'
 GROUP BY recommendations.id
 ORDER BY datecreated DESC
```

Which seems to work, as far as I can see (I'm no SQL expert). It returns all of the records from the Recommendations table that would be 'relevant' to a given user. However, I'm now having trouble also getting data from the Users table as well. The Recommendations table has the sender's and recipient's ID (foreign keys), but I'd also like to get the first and last name of each as well. I think I require some sort of JOIN, but I'm lost on how to proceed, and was looking for help on that. (And also, if anyone sees any areas for improvement in my current query, I'm all ears.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, believe I figured it out. Had to create 2 aliases of the users table, so that I could pull from each. Here's the working query:

```
SELECT recommendations.*, user1.firstname AS 'senderFirstName', user1.lastname AS 'senderLastName', user2.firstname AS 'recipientFirstName', user2.lastname AS 'recipientLastName'
FROM (recommendations, users)
INNER JOIN users AS user1 ON (user1.id=recommendations.sender)
INNER JOIN users AS user2 ON (user2.id=recommendations.recipient)
WHERE recommendations.sender IN (SELECT sender FROM relationships WHERE recipient='4' AND status='accepted' UNION SELECT recipient FROM relationships WHERE sender='4' AND status='accepted') OR recommendations.recipient IN (SELECT sender FROM relationships WHERE recipient='4' AND status='accepted' UNION SELECT recipient FROM relationships WHERE sender='4' AND status='accepted')
UNION
SELECT recommendations.*, user1.firstname AS 'senderFirstName', user1.lastname AS 'senderLastName', user2.firstname AS 'recipientFirstName', user2.lastname AS 'recipientLastName'
FROM (recommendations, users)
INNER JOIN users AS user1 ON (user1.id=recommendations.sender)
INNER JOIN users AS user2 ON (user2.id=recommendations.recipient)
WHERE recommendations.sender='4' OR recommendations.recipient='4'
GROUP BY recommendations.id
ORDER BY date created DESC
```

If anyone sees any errors or room for improvement, I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: If you're open to using a 3rd party service instead of rolling your own, http://www.collabinate.com may be an easier solution to challenges like this.

Comment: Anyone coming across this now- don't ever, ever do this.

Comment: Haha... Do you care to explain why?